# How to get all the audiences from the Audience Targeting which are added rule as Location user profile property Programmatically c#?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, user-profile, audience-targeting

I need to get all the audiences which are added a rule with Location user profile property under manage audiences section programmatically using C#, I tried

```
 SPServiceContext sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(newSite);
 AudienceManager audienceManager = new AudienceManager(sc);
 AudienceCollection ac = audienceManager.Audiences;
```

but I can't, Please suggest me some idea to achieve this?

Comment: There's not enough context to really know what you're asking for. Are you asking for the members of an audience? Navigation elements with restricted audiences? `locations` is very unclear. Please edit your question to describe exactly what you're looking for, thanks!

Comment: please be specific on what you want to do....thanks!

Comment: I Updated the Question@SiddharthVaghasia